# How to unpublish npm packages in nexus oss

Tags: npm, nexus

I've setup an Nexus (2.10.0) NPM repository and administrate an user with full access to this repo.
By setting the "_auth" and "always-auth" param in my local .npmrc the publishing and reading of npm artifacts are working well. But if i try to unpublish or deprecate an npm artifact i get still an error "...This request requires auth credentials. Run `npm login` and repeat the request...".

What is the preferred way to remove artifacts from an nexus npm repository?

thx,
David

Answer (score 3):

Unpublish is currently not supported. Details see https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6892

Also keep in mind that is not considered good practice to use unpublish as you can see from the npm documentation itself linked in the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the *npm deprecate* doesn't work well. Same error: `...This request requires auth credentials. Run npm login and repeat the request...` Is there actually an way to remove (or deprecate) artifacts from nexus npm repo via npm command?

Comment: Not currently from what I know but we are working on that. Please comment on the logged issues about your findings.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Nexus 2.11 doesn't support `npm unpublish` or `npm deprecate`.

**If the goal is to make your previously published versions of npm-packages inaccessible:**
You can delete the packages from Nexus by manually removing the tarballs from `.../nexus/storage/<your_npm_repo>/<your_package>/-/` on your Nexus server and creating a [scheduled task](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/scheduled-tasks.html) to **'rebuild hosted npm metadata'**:

> The npm metadata for a hosted repository
>   can be rebuilt based on the components found in the storage of a
>   hosted repository. The task can serve as a recovery tool in cases
>   where the npm metadata database got corrupted or the component storage
>   was created manually or via some external process like e.g. an rsync
>   copying.

This also works great for injecting old versions of packages into your npm-repo. (To get these tarballs, use `npm pack`.)

Comment: For info, NXRM3 supports npm deprecate.